# Multiple Conditional Statements in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, select, menu, if-statement, conditional-statements

I haven't used JavaScript for sometime.

I'm trying to get this following script working so if I select "Ireland" in the dropdown, the Ireland select menu appears below. The same goes for America and Canada.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcgarriers/DPSe4/

However it's just not working. Can anyone take a look and explain why?

I'm sure it's something simple.

Many thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its working :

http://jsfiddle.net/DPSe4/3/

You needed to pass the "SELECT" node to the function , instead of the form.

Comment: Wow, that was simple :) Thank you so much for clearing this up. I'd been racking my brain crazy trying to resolve it. Have a great day!!

Comment: Will go "green" in 8 minutes time :D

Answer (score 0):

It is because of *this* keyword. Inside of your function it reffers to DOM window object. Use

```
<select onchange='switchStates(this)'>
....

<script>
    switchStates(Sender){
       alert(Sender.selectedIndex+"-"+Sender.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks, Jan. I've chosen DhruvPathak's answer this time, but I really appreciate your response here.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing this.form to the function, but you've not put the parameter into the function parameter list.  i.e.:

```
function switchStates( form ) {
  ...
}
```

Also, you're not referencing the form's select object; you need `form.dcountry.selectedIndex`

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you for taking the time to reply and help me out. I've selected the answer from DhruvPathak above but thanks for your comments and answer too.